# How to handle redis exceptions by using Spring Cache?

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I am currently working on a project which incorporates both spring data redis and Spring Cache. In spring data redis, I am calling redis by using the redis template. I handle all of the exceptions thrown by the redis template in a try catch block as so:

```
   try{
       // execute some operation with redis template
    }
    catch(RedisCommandTimeoutException ex){

    }
    catch(RedisBusyException ex){

    }
    catch(RedisConnectionFailureException ex){

    }
    catch(Exception ex){

    }
```

Can I use a similar try-catch block to handle exceptions coming from `@cacheable`?  how can I handle exceptions thrown by redis in cacheable?

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to define your own `CacheErrorHandler` which will handle `@Cachable`, `@CachePut`, and `@CacheEvict`.

You would define the `CacheErrorHandler`:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;

@Slf4j
public class CustomCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException e, Cache cache, Object o) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException e, Cache cache, Object o, Object o1) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException e, Cache cache, Object o) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException e, Cache cache) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

And then register it:

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;  
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class CachingConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport {  
    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new CustomCacheErrorHandler();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you talk about more about the exceptions thrown from the Jedis driver?. If I am using Jedis, where can I documentation regarding exception handling?

Comment: If you are using the spring cacheable annotations, I would imagine the `CacheErrorHandler` that you define would catch the exceptions thrown by the underlying driver provider. (Jedis in your case)

Comment: How can I check which exceptions are thrown?

Comment: Without testing myself, I would implement the above, turn the app on, and then attempt to cause issues. (Ex. turn redis off while attempting a cache put) You should be able to see from the log output if `CustomCacheErrorHandler` is working as you would expect.