# How to prevent all RedisConnectionFailureException when Redis cache is not available

Tags: java, spring, caching, redis

I have this cacheable method inside my service *mocksConnector*:

```
@Cacheable(value = GET_PRODUCT_CACHE)
public ProductDetailMock getProduct(final String productId) {
    ...
}
```

If I run this code with Redis cache up everything works fine:

```
mocksConnector.getProduct(productId)
```

but if I stop Redis then RedisConnectionFailureException is thrown (makes sense)

[image]

Imagine that the data is critical and the method `getProduct` should always return something.

**Is there any way to configure the cache to automatically run the body of the method `getProduct` instead of simply failing?**

Please, note that I am searching for a general configuration (or a configuration at the method level, maybe?). I know that I can configure the cache manually and use *try/catch* blocks like:

```
try {
    redisClient.get(key)
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Do something else...
}
```

but I prefer not to do that.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by overriding the cache error handlers using a *CustomCacheErrorHandler* that does not throw any exception. See response from *Welsh* in [How to handle redis exceptions by using Spring Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65853418/how-to-handle-redis-exceptions-by-using-spring-cache?rq=1)

First, create a class

```
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;

public class CustomCacheErrorHandler implements CacheErrorHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleCacheGetError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        // Do nothing or log error
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCachePutError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key, Object value) {
        // Do nothing or log error
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheEvictError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache, Object key) {
        // Do nothing or log error
    }

    @Override
    public void handleCacheClearError(RuntimeException exception, Cache cache) {
        // Do nothing or log error
    }
}
```

then override the `CacheErrorHandler` from the configuration

```
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachingConfigurerSupport;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {
    ...

    @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new CustomCacheErrorHandler();
    }
}
```

Now we can use a service with Redis cache even when the cache is not available.

Comment: Hey Ruben, thanks for this as I just hit the same problem. Question though, I'm seeing a massive delay before the handleCacheGetError is getting fired. Is there away to shorten the connection timeout?

Comment: Hello!
You can use this property in your spring boot application: spring.redis.timeout (Read timeout.)
For example: spring.redis.timeout=100ms